# .Net Replacement for CodeMax (Embedded Code Editor Component for COM)

Tags: .net, editor

I used CodeMax for many years as a VBScript code editor, syntax highlighter and intellisense. However, it does not look like it is being updated anymore. I have tried to find a replacement to be used in a WPF/Silverlight 3 app but I have not found one yet. I did find [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) but that is just a wrapper for [a non .Net control](http://scintilla.org/) and I would prefer a native .Net component.

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Dan R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found one](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/(S(pvuw3zfgcvfhid55prs1bo45))/AvalonEdit.ashx) by the makers of SharpDevelop.